# Prometheus metrics from custom exporter display in /metrics, but not in /graph (k8s)

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I've written a node exporter in golang named "my-node-exporter" with some collectors to show metrics. From my cluster, I can view my metrics just fine with the following:

```
kubectl port-forward my-node-exporter-999b5fd99-bvc2c 9090:8080 -n kube-system
localhost:9090/metrics
```

However when I try to view my metrics within the prometheus dashboard

```
kubectl port-forward prometheus-prometheus-operator-158978-prometheus-0 9090
localhost:9090/graph
```

my metrics are nowhere to be found and I can only see default metrics. Am I missing a step for getting my metrics on the graph?

---

Here are the pods in my default namespace which has my prometheus stuff in it.

```
pod/alertmanager-prometheus-operator-158978-alertmanager-0            2/2     Running   0          85d
pod/grafana-1589787858-fd7b847f9-sxxpr                                1/1     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-158978-operator-75f4d57f5b-btwk9              2/2     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-1589787700-grafana-5fb7fd9d8d-2kptx           2/2     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-1589787700-kube-state-metrics-765d4b7bvtdhj   1/1     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-1589787700-prometheus-node-exporter-bwljh     1/1     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-1589787700-prometheus-node-exporter-nb4fv     1/1     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-operator-1589787700-prometheus-node-exporter-rmw2f     1/1     Running   0          85d
pod/prometheus-prometheus-operator-158978-prometheus-0                3/3     Running   1          85d
```

I used helm to install prometheus operator.

EDIT: adding my yaml file

```
# Configuration to deploy
#
# example usage: kubectl create -f <this_file>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter-sa
  namespace: kube-system

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: my-node-exporter-sa
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: my-node-exporter-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["storageclasses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---
#####################################################
############  Service ############
#####################################################

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter-svc
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: my-node-exporter
spec:
  ports:
    - name: my-node-exporter
      port: 8080
      targetPort: metrics
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-node-exporter

---
#########################################################
############   Deployment  ############
#########################################################

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-exporter
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-node-exporter
    spec:
      serviceAccount: my-node-exporter-sa
      containers:
        - name: my-node-exporter
          image: locationofmyimagehere
          args:
            - "--telemetry.addr=8080"
            - "--telemetry.path=/metrics"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: log-dir
              mountPath: /var/log
      volumes:
        - name: log-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
```

Service monitor yaml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter-service-monitor
  labels:
    app: my-node-exporter-service-monitor
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-exporter
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: app, operator: Exists}
  endpoints:
  - port: my-node-exporter
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - default
    - kube-system
```

Prometheus yaml

```
# Prometheus will use selected ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: my-node-exporter
  labels:
    team: frontend
spec:
  serviceMonitorSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: my-node-exporter
      matchExpressions:
      - key: app
        operator: Exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell Prometheus what metrics to collect - and where from - by firstly creating a `Service` that points to your `my-node-exporter` pods (if you haven't already), and then a `ServiceMonitor`, as described in the [Prometheus Operator docs](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md) - search for the phrase "This Service object is discovered by a ServiceMonitor".

Comment: I already have a service created. I created the servicemonitor yaml file as they described, and set "app" to my-node-exporter, and nothing changed. I also tried setting "app" to the service, my-node-exporter-svc, since it was unclear which one I was supposed to use. I created the servicemonitor in the default namespace along with my prometheus deployments.

Comment: You can take a look at the default `ServiceMonitor`s which come with the Prometheus Operator installation, see how they're defined. If you still can't get it to work, can you please show the exact definitions of your `Deployment`, `Service` and `ServiceMonitor`?

Comment: I've added my full yaml. Would adding my exporter to the scrape configs be necessary as denoted here? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#configuring-prometheus-to-monitor-itself. I've done it and it hasn't helped either.

Comment: Looks like in your `ServiceMonitor` you're addressing a port name that's not defined in your `Service`: `port: my-node-exporter`. [This diagram](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/custom-metrics-elements.png) looks useful in creating a mental model of how things should be connected together.

Comment: I've made changes to the yaml files and updated them above as well, trying to match what they did in that chart to the best of my abilities. Still don't see my exporter under targets or on the graph yet. Added my prometheus yaml as well to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Deployment/Service/ServiceMonitor/PrometheusRule working in `PrometheusOperator` needs great caution.
So I created a helm chart repo [kehao95/helm-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/kehao95/helm-prometheus-exporter) to install any prometheus-exporters, including your customer exporter, you can try it out.
It will create not only the exporter `Deployment` but also `Service`/`ServiceMonitor`/`PrometheusRule` for you.

- install the chart

```
helm repo add kehao95 https://kehao95.github.io/helm-prometheus-exporter/
```

- create an value file `my-exporter.yaml` for `kehao95/prometheus-exporter`

```yaml
exporter: 
  image: your-exporter
  tag: latest
  port: 8080
  args:
  - "--telemetry.addr=8080"
  - "--telemetry.path=/metrics"
```

- install it with helm

```
helm install --namespace yourns my-exporter kehao95/prometheus-exporter -f my-exporter.yaml
```

Then you should see your metrics in prometheus.